# ICAL.NET Recurring Elements: Fifth or Last Sunday of every Month

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, icalendar

The ical attachment (.ics) works for every case except fifth or last week of the month. I'm trying to create a recurrence for fifth or last Sunday of every month. When I open the .ics file, it says "The operation failed".

This is what is being passed in the code. It works if BYDAY (week) is 1-4.

```
{FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=3;COUNT=2;BYDAY=5SU}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't simply *"Last Sunday of every month"*  - `FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU` solve your issue? I might be mistaken but isn't the 5th Sunday always the last Sunday?

Comment: Btw.: Did you try the [RRULE Generator Tool](https://icalendar.org/rrule-tool.html)?

Comment: BYDAY=-1SU worked! Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BYDAY should be **-1** if it is the **Fifth** or **Last** week.

`FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU`

Comment: could you please help on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61193432/ical-net-recurring-elements-every-tuesdayweekly-every-2nd-last-mondaymonth